# angular2 modules: Dependency Injection with OpaqueToken works from JS Module, but not inline

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm following the angular docs for Dependency Injection and tried to duplicate the section on  [dependency injection tokens](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens).

define OpaqueToken in separate JS module

```
// app-config.ts
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export let APP_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken('app.config');

// use class instead of interface
export interface AppConfig {
  apiEndpoint: string;
  title: string;
}

export const HERO_DI_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: 'api.heroes.com',
  title: 'Dependency Injection'
};
```

import `APP_CONFIG` & ALSO define `APP_CONFIG2`

```
// app-modules.ts
import { APP_CONFIG, HERO_DI_CONFIG } from './app-config.ts';
export let APP_CONFIG2 = new OpaqueToken('app.config2');

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: HERO_DI_CONFIG},
    {provide: APP_CONFIG2, useValue: HERO_DI_CONFIG},
  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

and `inject` into a Component constructor

```
// app.ts
import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from './app-config.ts'
import { APP_CONFIG2 } from './app-module.ts'

export class App {
  constructor(
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG) public opaqueToken: AppConfig
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG2) public opaqueToken2: any
  ) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.local = LOCAL_STRING
  }
}
```

`APP_CONFIG` which is defined in an external module is injected correctly, but `APP_CONFIG2`, which was defined in the same module as the `provide` throws an error. Why is that?

`VM466 zone.js:323Error: (SystemJS) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for App: (Token_app_config, ?,`

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/5TkKAozC2vjXI9DfjMLg?p=preview

Comment: I just discovered the same issue with Angular 2.1.0. But I don't have a better solution than what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with Angular, but with circular dependencies between es6 modules.

In your example, `app.ts` imports `APP_CONFIG` from `app.module.ts` 
and `app.module.ts` imports `App` from `app.ts`.

This creates a circular dependency which cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you have to export `APP_CONFIG2` from `app-config.ts` and import it from `app-config.ts` in your `app-modules.ts` and `app.ts` file :

```
// app-config.ts
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export let APP_CONFIG = new OpaqueToken('app.config');
export let APP_CONFIG2 = new OpaqueToken('app.config');
```

Comment: I know that I can export an OpaqueToken from the `app-config.ts` module, that is what I did for `APP_CONFIG`.  But I do NOT understand why I cannot also export a different OpaqueToken inline from the same module that is calling `{provide: useValue:}`  That was the question.